# Dynamically added Labels don't appear

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a few Labels and a bunch of TextBoxes that I want to dynamically add to a Panel. The TextBoxes are are added OK and are perfectly visible, but the Labels are not. Here is the code I'm using to add the Labels.

The language is C# written for .NET 3.5 WinForms application.

```
Label lblMotive = new Label();
lblMotive.Text = language.motive;
lblMotive.Location = new Point(0, 0);

Label lblDiagnosis = new Label();
lblDiagnosis.Text = language.diagnosis;
lblDiagnosis.Location = new Point(20, 0);

panelServiceMotive.Controls.Add(lblMotive);
panelServiceMotive.Controls.Add(lblDiagnosis);
```

panelServiceMotive is the Panel control that should display the Labels, as well as the earlier mentioned TextBoxes. language is an object of a self-written Language class which works OK and is irrelevant here.

I hope that's enough info to get help.

Comment: first: sure that `language.motive != string.empty && language.diagnosis != string.empty` ? second: check the location (0,0), you sure you want them both at the same location?

Comment: I think you have to check text of label.

Comment: You are adding labels to same location `new Point(0, 0)`. Verify maybe you are later added textbox there

Comment: @derape The texts are "Motive" and "Diagnosis" respectively. I've checked those and they are OK.
lazyberezovsky Doesn't matter, those are just random numbers that I forgot to change, they don't appear anywhere no matter where I put them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the the main problem is the location of the controls that you add to the panel. The `Location` property holds the coordinates of the upper left edge of the control relative to the upper left corner of the parent control (the control in which you add child controls). Looking at your code, it appears that you add controls one on top of the other. Note that you always set `lblDiagnosis.Location = new Point(0, 0);`. If you add controls from code, the first control that you add will cover all the other controls that you add at the same location (unlike when using designer).

You could try something like this to check if the labels are ok:

```
Label lblMotive = new Label();
lblMotive.Text = language.motive;
lblMotive.Location = new Point(0, 40);

Label lblDiagnosis = new Label();
lblDiagnosis.Text = language.diagnosis;
lblDiagnosis.Location = new Point(0, lblMotive.Location.Y + lblMotive.Size.Height + 10);

panelServiceMotive.Controls.Add(lblMotive);
panelServiceMotive.Controls.Add(lblDiagnosis);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the panel is visible? Set its border or check its size.

Comment: Something like this does seem to work. It seems that the panel doesn't like 0 coordinate on either X or Y axis. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I just threw your code into an empty form application and it works perfectly fine:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Panel panelServiceMotive = new Panel();

  Label lblMotive = new Label();
  lblMotive.Text = "motive";
  lblMotive.Location = new Point(0, 0);

  Label lblDiagnosis = new Label();
  lblDiagnosis.Text = "language";
  lblDiagnosis.Location = new Point(100, 0);

  panelServiceMotive.Controls.Add(lblMotive);
  panelServiceMotive.Controls.Add(lblDiagnosis);

  this.Controls.Add(panelServiceMotive);
}
```

Something else must be wrong with your code which we can't see from your posted code.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's possible that the Panel itself overlaps with some controls. Already solved, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

What are you setting the text to in 'language.Motive' 'language.diagnosis' is this coming from a resource file or string const or something?

I suggest you set these to a hard coded value or check to make sure there not null first.

Also try changing the location of the textbox as they maybe overlapping each other.

Comment: As I said, it's a custom class I've written, and the texts are "Motive" and "Diagnosis" respectively. I've checked those and they are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to add the Labels at run-time? A simpler approach would be add the Labels in form designer and update the text at run-time. If the number of Labels required isn't known at design-time, a different control, such as a ListBox or a DataGridView may be more suitable. Alternatively, look at the the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx) as an alternative container for the Labels; unlike a regular Panel, it manages the layout of Controls automatically.